# How to render <ol> with proper indentation and label using react-native-render-html?

Tags: react-native, html-lists, react-quill, react-native-render-html

I'm using the *renderers* to alter the indention of the levels however I needed to provide a custom function to identify the proper label.

Here's the payload returned from the API >>>>

```
<p>sample product</p>
<p><br></p>
<ol>
   <li>sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-1" id="a">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-1" id="a">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-2" id="i">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-2" id="i">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-2" id="i">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-1" id="a">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-1" id="a">sample </li>
   <li class="ql-indent-2" id="i">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-3" id="1">sample</li>
   <li class="ql-indent-4" id="a">sample</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hi Toni, and welcome to Stackoverflow! Just as a kind reminder of the rules, please [do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). As per your issue, the current version you seem to be using (5.x) does not provide much extensibility for targeting list nest levels. Version 6.x however should be much better at this. Still in alpha; I'll post a full response when the release goes beta.

Comment: Would you mind adding the CSS rules for those classes and the desired output?